# SQL: using UNIQUE for column pokemon_master_id

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, unique-index

**EDITED: I recognize that some of you might wonder why I have 2 'id' values in my SQL code. I have addressed why in my particular case it seems to be needed in the comment below this question.**

Given the following SQL code for creating table pokemon_users:

```
CREATE TABLE pokemon_users (
user_id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
pokemon_master_id BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
message varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)
```

**QUESTION 1:** *would an index be created for column pokemon_master_id?*

**QUESTION 2:** *If so, what would be the difference between the index created for the PRIMARY KEY (user_id), and the pokemon_master_id index?*

Comment: Do you really need _two_ unique numbers for the same user?

Comment: @Rick James For my specific case yes, well at least for technical reasons it was the solution I adopted. For example, lets say you use the Facebook SDK for PHP and get the users Facebook id, and then in your website you need to display a unique value for each user publicly. For security reasons, I would assume that displaying the facebook_id facebook provides you would be bad, hence creating a different unique ID would be fitting in that case, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: You present a good case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1**: Yes. A unique index.

**Question 2**: The primary key user_id is also a unique index. The difference is that you can only have one primary key but many unique indexes on a table.

Comment: My initial comment was not quite correct: The primary index (by default) determines the physical storage order, this is not the case for the unique index. However, in most SQL versions you can change what index is clustered. In that scenario the clustered index will determine the physical storage order.

Comment: In MySQL, with "engine=InnoDB", a `PRIMARY KEY` is always (not just 'by default') unique and clustered with the data.